# Using language specific resources for models in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am interested how to display language based notification in view using a predefined models.

For example this is a part of my model:

```
public class PrivateModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill in your last name.")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill in your last name.")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

    }
```

And here is the view:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)

    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="First click"
    </div>
```

What would I do if I want to have error message for First Name to be in different languages.

Is it possible to replace actual values with IDs of language resource and use something like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "100")]//Please enter your first name
            [Display(Name = "101")]// First name
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

and then instead of

```
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
```

use

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => GetSource(m.FirstName, culture))
```

Comment: Can you use resource files?

Comment: @DanielJ.G. i already have a DB that I must use

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the:

```
ErrorMessageResourceName
```

of the data annotations attributes.

Then you can store all your messages in localized resource files and the key will then lookup the string based on the selected localization.

Globalisation is a massive topic but this should get you started.

Comment: i have to use db instead resource files. Would ErrorMessageResourceName would solve issue for Display? Basically if only solution is using resource files, I just want to know how to implement idea i provided

Comment: I'm questioning the architecture here.  Mixing presentation and the database isn't a particular well thought out process to my mind.  Unless the database is specifically designed for this and is a separate entity from the application database.  Each page view is going to produce a stack of queries against the database for each of the required string.  Do you really want that kind of traffic hitting the database for every single page view?

Comment: DB results are being cached

Answer (score 0):

see below links for Localization complete guide

http://adamyan.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/internationalization

```
public class LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
{
  private PropertyInfo _nameProperty;
  private Type _resourceType; //Declare Cache object here to select property name

  public LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute(string displayNameKey)
      : base(displayNameKey)
  {

  }

  public Type NameResourceType
  {
      get
      {
          return _resourceType;
      }
      set
      {
          _resourceType = value;
          //initialize nameProperty when type property is provided by setter
      // _nameProperty = _resourceType.GetProperty(base.DisplayName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
          _nameProperty = select property from Cache values for Database 
      }
  }

  public override string DisplayName
  {
     get
     {
          //check if nameProperty is null and return original display name value
          if (_nameProperty == null)
          {
              return base.DisplayName;
          }

          return (string)_nameProperty.GetValue(_nameProperty.DeclaringType, null);
      }
   }
```

Comment: sorry, but cant use resource files

Comment: Then you have to declare your own and use LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute .